# flutter Multipart file upload server side error: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided

Tags: servlets, multipartform-data

Flutter:

```
var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", url);
request.fields['name'] = 'John';
request.files.add(http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
    'file1',
    '/path/to/file1.jpg',
));
var response = await request.send();
```

On server side java servlet:

```
 request.getParts();
```

throw exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2866)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2834)
```

request.getContentType() is correct, returning "multipart/form-data; ...".

Comment: You forgot the `@MultipartConfig` annotation on the servlet. See abovelinked dupe.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `await` before `http.MultipartFile.fromPath`

```
var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", url);
request.fields['name'] = 'John';
request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
    'file1',
    '/path/to/file1.jpg',
));
var streamedResponse = await request.send();
var response = Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);
```

You should be getting at servlet side after this change.

Comment: comment by @BalusC solved the problem.